# citep generates author name twice

Tags: cross-referencing, citing

I have a problem which I don't understand

```
@article{spillner,
  author={A.Spillner},
  title={The W-MODEL – Strengthening the Bond Between Development and Test},
  publisher={University of Applied Sciences Bremen Germany}
}
```

This is one of my reference inside mybib.bib

I am trying to cite this reference inside my latex file with

```
\citep{spillner}
```

What I expected from this was I will get (A.Spillner), but now I get (A.Spillner, A.Spillner).
What is wrong with my LaTex?

This is sample of my LaTex file

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\usepackage{url}

\title{Article 1}
\author{Secret haha}
\date{02-25-2022}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

Some text

\section{Question 1 }
Text text text ... According to~\cite{Myers:2012:book}, Text text text text 

Text text text activities~\citep{spillner}. Text text text text


\textbf{Study Question Text:}  

\section{Qestion 13}


%%END YOUR PART
\bibliographystyle{chicago}
\bibliography{mybib.bib}
%% Follow the standard entry of bibtex 
\end{document}
```

Comment: please provide a small but complete test file that shows that output, to allow people to debug the issue.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I posted it now. Check that. The first cite works as I thought but the citep shows same author name twice

Comment: Off-topic: Don't use the `@article` entry type for entries that weren't published in a scholarly journal. For the entry at hand, I'd recommend using either `@misc` or `@unpublished`.

Comment: @Mico thanks, I will change article to misc or unpublished. But I still see author name twice. Should I avoid to cite if I don't know the year?

Comment: Whenever you make use of somebody else's thoughts and ideas in your own work but fail to cite their contribution properly, you are at serious risk of committing plagiarism. Not having information about the publication year is neither a valid reason nor an excuse for failing to cite a contribution. As I show in my answer, what you need to backfill is information about the publication year, since you're using a bibliography style that outputs authoryear-style citation call-outs. If, after a reasonable search, you still can't find the publication year, just write `year = {N.D.}` in the bib entry.

Answer (score 2):

The `chicago` bib style (which, by the way, is quite old and hence no longer represents *current* "Chicago" formatting practices) is programmed to generate author-year citation call-outs. But since the `spillner` entry is lacking a `year` field, BibTeX has to come up with some kind of substitute for the year of the publication. I guess you've found out that this substitute is the `author` field...

Moral of the story? Do yourself a favor and provide a `year` field for all entries.

Oh, please also change `author={A.Spillner},` to `author={A. Spillner},` -- can you spot the difference? -- so that BibTeX has a chance to recognize the surname as "Spillner", not "A.Spillner". (I think the author's given name is "Andreas". "A." is definitely not part of the surname...

Comment: What should I do if there is no year given on the document which I have? It's part of my course materials and I cannot find any year

Comment: @user264409 -- What kind of search did you perform? According to https://www.stickyminds.com/presentation/w-model-strengthening-bond-between-development-and-test, the piece was presented at a conference in 2002. That would make 2002 a leading candidate for the publication year, no? Oh, and the piece has **two authors** -- Andreas Spillner and Karin Vosseberg -- and not just one.

Comment: I did not do any search, pdf was already uploaded in my university course homepage

Comment: No, I am not exerting myself. It was just an answer to your question  "What kind of search did you perform?". Thank you for the link. I will read it and apply to my document.